# Distribution Enterprise app for iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, ios-enterprise

I would distribute app for iOS 6.

Actually I have XCode 8.2.1 and if I try to distribute with this version of XCode the app doen't work on iOS 6 but works with the highter versions.

So I tried to to distribute my app with XCode 6.4 but it doesn't work either on iOS 6, but works perfecty with highter versions.

I'm starting to think that MAYBE, just MAYBE, the app installation il locked by o.s of iOS.

Can someone help me to understand the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> The minimum deployment target with Xcode 8 is iOS 8. To support target
>   the iOS SDK 7.x and below, use Xcode 7.
>
> If you try to use a deployment target of iOS 7.x or below, Xcode will
>   suggest you change your target to iOS 8

*And Mac OS Sierra you cannot start Xcode 7.x as it crashes on launch due to a missing library.*
[image]